# Trademark considerations when naming .NET assemblies

Tags: c#, dll, naming

We have an application and some of its assemblies, that are generated by us, are named Microsoft.*.dll

Is that OK from a legal point of view?

If not, is there a specific reference on Microsoft's website clearly stating this is prohibited? 
I searched and couldn't find one.

Comment: They are com object in the windows/system32 folder.  So if you distribute your software and say it would run on Windows is that a trademark infringement?  The com object are not copied in the release.

Comment: Not sure I understand the point you're making

Comment: Really "using Microsoft" is no difference from "using System" since Microsoft is a namespace in the Microsoft Windows Library as well as System is a namespace in the Microsoft Net Library.  If your software runs on windows, you have to take the same considerations that you would in saying the software runs on windows as using Microsoft on you module.

Answer (score 2):

Stackoverflow is not the right place to ask legal questions but the [official design guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-assemblies-and-dlls) says you should consider naming DLLs according to `<Company>.<Component>.dll` where `<Company>` is the name of the manufacturer.

Microsoft is not the manufacturer of your assemblies and it is a registered trademark with all that it entails.

In short, don't use their name. If not illegal, it's a least confusing for any consumer of your assemblies.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Confusing for sure, but I was especially interested in the legal part. I also looked at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/intellectualproperty/trademarks/usage/general.aspx but it's still not clear to me if it is forbidden from a legal perspective to have the name of the dll start with Microsoft.

Comment: Before asking a lawyer about this, I wanted to check if anyone can point to a resource online that can provide a more black-and-white view. Didn't want to bother the lawyer for nothing. There is the possibility that someone already faced this issue and could tell me if it had legal implications.